# Documenting multiple attributes using rdoc

Tags: ruby, rdoc

Is there a way to document each of the following attributes without breaking them into separate declarations?

```
attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
```

As opposed to:

```
# description for a
attr_accessor :a
# description for b
attr_accessor :b
# description for c
attr_accessor :c
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
attr_accessor :a, :b, :c # description for a, b and c respectively
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do a call to atrr_accessor for each documented attribute.

If you rather have them ignored you can always add # :nodoc: at the end of the line.